# Is this an effective and efficient SQL Query or is there a better way?

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

We have a passwords table which references a user table.  Records never get deleted from the password table so if a user changes their password, a new entry with a more recent `Created` date gets inserted.

The hash of the password is salted with various things, most importantly the created date of the actual record.

In a stored procedure, I'm retrieving variables so I can do a hash for comparison.  I really just want to store the most recent password hash for a user along with the record's created date:

```
DECLARE @ExistingPassword as varchar(200)
DECLARE @LastChanged as DateTime

SELECT Top 1
    @ExistingPassword = p.PasswordHash,
    @LastChanged = p.Created, 
FROM Password as p
WHERE p.UserId = @UserId
ORDER BY p.Created DESC
```

Is this a reasonably efficient way of getting the most recent password hash and its created date?  Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: that entirely depends on the size of the tables, what indexes are in place and how fragmented the indexes are.

Comment: @Mitch - Yes, point taken, that'll make a big difference. For background, we're talking about maybe 50,000 users, and they can change their passwords as regularly as they like. Over time though, a user may end up with a few hundred passwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is efficient, but I would make sure there is an index on:

```
userId and created
```

for performance reasons

Comment: +1.  As long as the index is there, `TOP 1 ORDER BY` will resolve to a 1-row index seek which is pretty much the fastest you can get.  Just make sure the index is **covering** (i.e. `INCLUDE (ExistingPassword, LastChanged)`).

Answer (score 1):

I think that is the fastest way to do it.  I ran the below code to test your way and the only other way I could think of and your way was a little faster.  I would also like to mention in a table with 1,000,000 rows I was getting response times fast enough that SSMS was not even giving me a run time, just 00:00:00.  I did see one thing that might help you.  If you can, put a non-clustered index on the Created column and make it sort in Descending order.  Putting it in Descending order will make big difference because it will stop you from doing a table scan for the newest Created DateTime.  That really could make a HUGE difference.

```
--Put Rows in TestTable, 3 Rows ID, User_ID, CreatedTime
DECLARE @Count INT
SET @Count = 1

WHILE @Count <= 1000000
BEGIN

INSERT INTO TestTable
VALUES (@Count%3+1,DATEADD(HH,@Count,getdate()))

SET @Count = @Count + 1

END

--Select Your way
SELECT TOP 1
 User_ID
FROM TestTable
WHERE User_ID = 3
ORDER BY CreatedTime DESC

--Select my way
SELECT
 User_ID
FROM TestTable
WHERE User_ID = 3
 and CreatedTime = (SELECT MAX(CreatedTime) FROM TestTable WHERE User_ID = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

By my personal experience, you should work with a period, like `StartDate` and `EndDate`. So, you can to use a `WHERE getdate() BETWEEN StartDate and EndDate` to search for your current password.

Every time you add a record just with a created date for subsequent most update retrieval, baby jesus cries.

Comment: The difficulty is that user requirements specify that a person's password doesn't have to expire (not my idea). In this context, there is no `EndDate`.

Comment: So `@EndDate = '2199-12-31'`, until you get a new one, when you set actual EndDate to yesterday and new one starting on today

Comment: I see what you're saying, but that means any insert would have to insert a new record and update existing records to expire the `EndDate` - extra work.  The select query would then have an extra `WHERE EndDate < @EndDate` clause which is fairly pointless if `@EndDate` is always 200 years in the future.  Useful if I change the way I'm doing it, sure, but the spec is already defined.